# Creating new columns in Sql Server based on other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table T :

```
CREATE TABLE T 
(
id INT,
type VARCHAR(200),
type_value VARCHAR(10),
value  VARCHAR(200)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,    'HomePhone',   'p1',    '1234 ');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,    'HomePhone',    'p2',    '5678 ');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,    'HomePhone',    'p3',    '4567');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,    'WorkPhone',    'w1',    '9007 ');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,    'Email',             'e1',    'abc@xyz.com ');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,    'Email',             'e1',    'efg@xyz.com');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,    'Email',             'e2',    'mno@xyz.com');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,    'WorkPhone',    'w1',    '0100');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,    'WorkPhone',    'w2',    '0110');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,    'OtherPhone',    'o1',    '1010 ');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,    'OtherPhone',    'o1',    '1110 ');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,    'OtherPhone',    'o1',    '1011');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,    'HomePhone',    'p1',    '2567 ');
```

I need to transform it into :

```
id   primaryhomephone    secondaryhomephone    primaryemail   secondaryemail   Primaryworkphone    secondaryworkphone    primaryotherphone   secondaryotherphone 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1234                5678                  null           null             9007                 null                 null                null
2    null                null                  abc@xyz.com    efg@xyz.com      null                 null                 null                null
3    null                null                  null           null             0100                 0110                 null                null
4    2567                null                  null           null             null                 null                 1010                1011
```

Basically the field will be divided based on type_value. If there is two  type_value for same id and type then first type will be primary and second type will be secondary.
For more than two type values for same id and type, discard the third one.
For more than two type values of same type(for example o1,o1) for id 4 first o1 will be primaryotherphone and second one will be secondaryprimaryphone. 
 
Sorry if this question has been repeated before but somehow I can't solve it. Can anyone please help. 
 Thanks a lot

Comment: Is that definite column list? I mean, that do you need dynamic solution, when you do not know exact number of columns or you know that there would only be primary and secondary columns?

Comment: Yes sure @DmitrijKultasev. Dynamic solutions will be great

Comment: Of course it will be great, but in that case you'll not be able to use just SELECT statements, you'll need to use EXEC ('statement') that would mean that you'll not be able to join this to anything else in the proper way.

Comment: Thanks @DmitrijKultasev. I think I will go with the static one :p I need to join the computed table with other tables.

Comment: You will not achieve that with computed columns. I'll remark. You can achieve that, but it is not the way you need to do here. You need to do PIVOT or MAX()/GROUP BY technique

Comment: I am looking into pivot right now.

Comment: What is "the first one"? What is the order to get the "first record"? What if there are more than 2 entries?

Comment: Discard the 3rd entry. If two entries present  for same id then take first one as primary and second one as secondary.  For example : If there are type_value p1,p2 for same id (different row) then p1 will be primary and p2 will be secondary or for type values p1,p1 for same id (different row) then first p1 will be primary and second p1 will be secondary or if there are two type values p2,p2 for same id (different row) then first p2 will be primary and second one will be secondary. Discard type_value p3 if present .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157717/discussion-between-sayantan-mukherjee-and-dmitrij-kultasev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look after [computed columns](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/using-computed-columns-persisted) in SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].T
(
   ...
   [primaryhomephone] AS (CASE WHEN type_value = 'p1' THEN value ELSE NULL END)
)
```

Alternatively you can use Views:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwT
AS
SELECT 
   id
   ,(CASE WHEN type_value = 'p1' THEN value ELSE NULL END as [primaryhomephone]
   , (CASE WHEN type_value = 'p2' THEN value ELSE NULL END as [secondaryhomephone]
FROM dbo.T
```

Comment: In case of computed columns, you'll have multiple records with NULLs, they will not appear in the same row.

Comment: I didn't indicate those columns as PERSISTED. Which option do you see more appropriate: view or computed columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MAX/GROUP BY technique. PIVOT is quite complex for beginners, but I agree that the purpose of the PIVOT is the exactly what you need:

```
SELECT id
, MAX(CASE WHEN type_value = 'p1' THEN value END ) AS primaryhomephone
, MAX(CASE WHEN type_value = 'p2' THEN value END ) AS secondaryhomephone
, MAX(CASE WHEN type_value = 'p3' THEN value END ) AS thirdphone
, MAX(CASE WHEN type_value = 'w1' THEN value END ) AS workphone
, MAX(CASE WHEN type_value = 'w2' THEN value END ) AS secondaryworkphone
, MAX(CASE WHEN type_value = 'o2' THEN value END ) AS otherworkphone
, MAX(CASE WHEN type_value = 'e1' THEN value END ) AS primaryemail
, MAX(CASE WHEN type_value = 'e2' THEN value END ) AS secondaryemail
FROM T
GROUP BY id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into `PIVOT` Column presentation. You can use it in to ways, you can create new Table with your column and then use `PIVOT` Query to insert them there, or you can simply fetch at runtime. If there is lot of data and all other Programming interface are ready to upgrade then make new table, else just use query.

Here is the link for your reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx